# Which texts are Brahmins allowed to read?

Tags: scripture, brahmins

Does scripture mention texts of Hindu or non-Hindu origin that would be sinful for Brahmins to read or prohibited by their Varna Dharma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Manu Smriti reading "bad books" is a minor sin (UpapAtaka) that leads to loss of caste.

Brahmins or Dvijas should not read such books.

> Manu Smriti 11.65. Neglecting to kindle the sacred fires, theft,
>   non-payment of (the three) debts, **studying bad books**, and
>   practising (the arts of) dancing and singing,
>
> 11.66. Stealing grain, base metals, or cattle, intercourse with women who drink spirituous liquor, slaying women, Sudras, Vaisyas, or
>   Kshatriyas, and atheism, **(are all) minor offences, causing loss of
>   caste (Upapataka).**

The original Sanskrit verse has "asat shAstra" which is translated as bad books. Probably it is talking about erotic literature.

But the literal meaning will be "false doctrines".

Comment: asat shastra means untruth book. By untruth, I think holy books of other religions.

Comment: I am not sure what it means may be u are right .. I thought it is talking about  erotic literature @NaveenKick

Comment: @Rickross Ashatsastra is probably means the atheists' books. Sat means ever-existing.So whatever is against sanatana is asat, like buddhist or jain texts i think:)

Comment: Yes like I said it literally means false doctrines .. @Partha

Comment: @NaveenKick I think books of other religions can be read with the intention of refuting it. Of course, everybody is not qualified to refute other doctrines.

Comment: @Rickross yes, but erotic is not necessarily asat, as we had vatsayana and one of the four apavargas is kama:)

Comment: 'sat' literally means good. 'asat' means 'not good'. There is nothing about truth. Brahmins can read and write fantasies :)