# Are non-Hindus secretly assisted by asuras and rakshasas in their translations of the Vedas?

Tags: asuras, rakshasa, mleccha

It is known that pitrs and devas assist brahmanas in their performance and dissemination of dharma, which includes interpretation of the vedas with the correct meaning.

It's also known that rakshasas and asuras have a malevolent influence in the spread of adharma on Earth through humans. For example, in the mahabharata war, Bhishma was possessed by a daitya (asura) to do adharmic acts.

My question is, are non-Hindus secretly assisted by asuras and rakshasas in their translations of the vedas to distort its meaning?

I have good reason to suspect that it is the case, but is there any definite scriptural backing to support this?

Comment: FYI: [It should not be allowed to call contemporary eminent Western Sanskrit scholars “Mlecchas”](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1826/it-should-not-be-allowed-to-call-contemporary-eminent-western-sanskrit-scholars)

Comment: @sv. Question is updated.

Comment: "are non-Hindus secretly assisted by asuras and rakshasas in their translations of the vedas to distort its meaning?" - who are these non-Hindus? seems off-topic and opinion-based question to me. asking "is there any definite scriptural backing to support this?" doesn't make it on-topic.

Comment: @Ikshvaku my personal opinion is yes. those westerners who intentionally distort Vedic scriptures are definitely asuric/demonic in nature.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Which translation of the Vedas by a non-Hindu isn't based on Sayana's? Then how Asuras involvement comes in the picture? Basically all of them are simply translating Sayana's commentary.

Comment: @SK You should not vote to close a question and answer it at the same time. When you know a question needs to be closed then you should only close it and not answer it like you've done.

Comment: @rickross - i retracted my close vote.  I think my answer needs to stand.

Comment: @Rickross Max Mueller based his translation on Sayana, but many Indologists today are coming up with their own translations based on Indo-European studies, according to SK.

Comment: @sv. "who are these non-Hindus?" - You saw, 'mlecchas'. But that word is too vulgar for this site, according to some.

Comment: @rishx - is intrepreting "tat tvam asi" as "atat tvam asi" (using a Sandhi trick) a distortion?  this is 100 per-cent Sanatani.

Comment: @SK That's a good point.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, according to Swami Vivekananda:

citing from HSE itself:

[Did the great Vedic scholar Sayanacharya reincarnate as Max Muller who propagated Aryan Invasion Theory?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32922/did-the-great-vedic-scholar-sayanacharya-reincarnate-as-max-muller-who-propagate/32935#32935)

> "mone holo ki jaanis, Sayan i nijer bhashya nije uddhar korte Max Muller hoye jonmechhen,aamaar anek din hoitei oi dhaarana." (Swami-Sishya-Samvad, Sarachchandra Chakraborti, Udbodhan, page 56)

> Meaning: Do you know what seemed to me? It was Sayana Himself who was born as Max Mueller to revive his commentaries. This is my "Dhaarana"(impression)

Another so-called "mleccha" Arthur Avalon made Tantric doctrines more available to everybody with his translations

https://www.tititudorancea.com/z/john_george_woodroffe_arthur_avalon_biography.htm

Rohan Murty is as Sanatana Dharmi as they come, and he has commissioned "Mleccha" scholar Sheldon Pollock for translating Sanskrit works for the Murty Classical library.

https://www.huffpost.com/archive/in/entry/2016/03/02/rohan-murty-pollock-removal_n_9371122.html

Don't see Asuras or Rakshasas anywhere.

Comment: I think he just said that because MM heavily used Sayana's commentary.

Comment: All Rohan Murthy has is his dad's millions to throw at anyone who can dazzle him.

Comment: There are several eminent Indian scholars who have criticized this Murthy Classical Library for its typical western academic biases in translations.

Comment: @ramabloh - it must be my purvajanma punya that you are here to enlighten me.

Comment: @RamAbloh While I respect your expertise at subject and you're welcome to critique the work as well, but in no way personal attack is acceptable here on HSE. Please refrain yourself from doing so.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto My first comment has been deleted completely. It had an important point, which is now fully gone. And I don't think there was any personal attack. What constitutes personal attack? If it is hidden under the guise of sarcasm (as done by SK above), does it go under the radar?

Comment: @RamAbloh This part especially: _"Rohan Murthy is as Sanatana Dharmi as Sheldon Pollock. He has no knowledge of Sanskrit, Vedas, or other scriptures, and not even a scent of traditional scholarship even if our noses are deep into his armpits. He doesn't have the depth of understanding to see what twisted theories Pollock has put forth in his attempt to undermine the role of Sanskrit."_

Comment: @RamAbloh If you find any comment which look rude or offensive or unfriendly, please use flag option to report to us.